# Would putting a pricing page on our website more likely improve the user experience if our competitors only offer ‘contact for quote’ pages?

Tags: usability, user-behavior, pricing, contact-us

I'm in-house at a medium size call center. I've been trying to get a pricing page put up for us on our website for a long time. If we're not the lowest price we'll price match as much as we possibly can.

The main reasons the price page has been squashed are: Everyone's always shopping everybody and trying to undercut everybody, and our quotes are completely custom based on the service a customer needs (although everything starts with a base and extras are added on as needed).

Does anyone have experience with customer feedback after a pricing page was put on their website, particularly in an industry where price is heavily guarded from one another and there are mostly "contact us for a quote" pages?

Comment: Showing customers what something costs would usually be argued as a *good* user experience and *encourage* sales. That said, maybe your product is priced ridiculously high and would deter sales. Really hard to say without knowing all the details.

Comment: This is a no-brainer from a UX point of view and I’m afraid the question phrased as is should be considered off-topic.

Comment: This article might be of interest to you: http://thenextweb.com/insider/2015/12/18/i-analyzed-250-saas-pricing-pages-heres-what-i-found/

Comment: And this hacker news thread on that article provides some good insight on why pricing pages for enterprise products are probably a good idea: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=10771567

Comment: Thank you all so much for the responses, it's been truly helpful!

Comment: @DA01 we are not the cheapest service, probably priced higher than at least half of competitive call centers (I'm assuming, since pricing is a closely guarded secret), but we're located in the US and we have extremely high standards, so the value is there.

Comment: @Crissov Yeah, I wasn't sure how to word it so that it fit, it's kind of in between marketing strategy and UX

Comment: @CodyReichert Thank you so much for the links, they're very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Sort of.

Over a decade ago I purchased an offset printing business and spent a couple of years bringing it into the 'digital age'. Part of this process included establishing a web page and an intranet quoting system (basically a pricing intranet website all built in HTML).

On our external website we made a bit of a big deal about being able to provide a quote immediately be it over the phone or in person. This was a major 'advantage' because most of our competitors would take days to get back with a quote (we used too as well, because there was usually a bit involved in working out a quote).

So I invested the time to work out the prices for a whole heap of 'standard' products (e.g. business cards, letterhead, brochures, posters, flyers, etc) of various quantities (e.g. 500, 1000, 2000, 5000, etc) and styles (e.g. single-sided, double-sided, B&W, full colour, 1 colour, 2 colour, etc). Now, this whole process literally took me two or three weeks full-time.

But, in the end, the result was well worth it. 95% of the time someone rang or came in we could quote them pretty much on the spot. And, when we were asked something that wasn't quite on our price list, we were able to find the closest match and make a 'guesstimate' which usually worked out pretty well.

When customers came in person, they could access the system from a couple of computers on the counter, or we could use them to give them quotes on the spot.

And the feedback I got was extremely positive, both from customers and my staff. It just made things so much easier for everyone all around.

So I would argue the user experience was much better all around.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!

Did it end up increasing your business?
Were there any negatives? Undercutting from your competition, etc?